# Como usar o Reference em uma assinatura de XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Dúvidas sobre `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference`:

1. Para que exatamente ele serve?
2. Como devo usar o Reference? O que atribuir a ele?
3. Preciso usar isso na assinatura de uma XML Pq?
4. E como usar?

O que fazer aqui?

```
Dim reference As New Reference()
reference.Uri = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. O Reference  representa o elemento de uma assinatura digital do XML definido pela especificação da assinatura digital (www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/).
2. Algumas propriedades disponíveis font: [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.reference(v=vs.110).aspx)

   **DigestMethod:**   Obtém ou define o método *digest URI Uniform Resource Identifier* do *Reference*.
   **DigestValue:**        Obtém ou define o valor de *digest* da atual *Reference*.
   **Id:**             Obtém ou define a identificação do atual *Reference*.
   **TransformChain**  Obtém a cadeia de transformação do atual *Reference*.
   **Type:**           Obtém ou define o tipo de objeto que está sendo assinado.
   **Uri:**                Obtém ou define o *Uri* do atual *Reference*.
3. Sim em conjunto outras classe, por exemplo `SignedXml`. Porque NFe sem assinatura simplesmente não é aceita pela SEFAZ.
4. Exemplo:

   > ```
   > ' Create a new XML document.
   > Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
   >
   > ' Format the document to ignore white spaces.
   > doc.PreserveWhitespace = False
   >
   > ' Load the passed XML file using it’s name.
   > doc.LoadXml(xmlString)
   >
   > Dim tagAss = "infNFe"
   > Dim ref As New Reference()
   > Dim _Uri As XmlAttributeCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagAss).Item(0).Attributes
   > For Each atributo As XmlAttribute In _Uri
   >   If atributo.Name = "Id" Then
   >       ref.Uri = "#" & atributo.InnerText
   >   End If
   > Next
   >
   > ' Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
   > Dim Envelope As New XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform()
   > Referencia.AddTransform(Envelope)
   >
   > Dim c14 As New XmlDsigC14NTransform()
   > ref.AddTransform(c14)
   >
   > ' Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
   > signedXml.AddReference(ref)
   >
   > ' Create a new KeyInfo object
   > Dim keyInfo As New KeyInfo()
   >
   > ' Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
   > ' and add it to the KeyInfo object.
   > keyInfo.AddClause(New KeyInfoX509Data(_X509Cert))
   >
   > ' Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
   > signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo
   > signedXml.ComputeSignature()
   >
   > ' Get the XML representation of the signature and save
   > ' it to an XmlElement object.
   > Dim xmlDigitalSignature As XmlElement = signedXml.GetXml()
   >
   > ' Gravar assinatura no documento XML
   > doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature,True))
   > XMLDoc = New XmlDocument()
   > XMLDoc.PreserveWhitespace = False
   > XMLDoc = doc 
   > dim xmlAssinado = XMLDoc.OuterXml
   > ```